# maven dependencies in profiles during release build

Tags: maven-2, release, maven

I have a maven module which has several dependencies that are contained in profiles. When preparing a release build using the release plugin (i.e. `mvn release:prepare`), the versions of those dependencies do not get replaced, instead they remain the SNAPSHOT dependencies, even though the profiles are active (we run `mvn release:prepare -Psomeprofile`). I have also tried adding `-Darguments="-Psomeprofile"` to the mvn call, but this did not help either.

How can I make the release plugin also replace the versions of dependencies that are contained in profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [MRELEASE-354](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-354), *"Versions defined in profiles are not updated"*. The workaround if to use

```
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

for the dependencies defined inside profiles.